# QGIS problems executing 'Filter' inside and outside of attribute table with ESRI FileGeodatabase

Tags: file-geodatabase, qgis-2.4

I'm working with a file geodatabase in QGIS and am having some issues with the 'Filter'.  These issues occur whether I'm applying the filter to the attribute table or directly to the layer (from the layers pane).

When I go to apply the filter and start writing my expression, all of my fields show up correctly and I can select the one I need, but when I try to view 'All' or 'Sample' of the available values, I'm receiving values from the first field that exists in the feature class.  So, for example, I want to filter on street name, but when I try to view all the values from the street name field, I believe I'm getting the values from the first field that exists in my feature class which is my RelateID field.

I have also noticed when say I'm trying to filter on say a street prefix (I have 7 potential values in my feature class), that is the same number of values that appear in the 'value' window on the side of the query box.  I haven't checked to see if they match up, but i'm guessing the 'value' I'm receiving is the first occurance of that 'Prefix' in my feature class.  Interestingly, when I manually enter my filter expression, "StreetName" = 'MINNESOTA' without getting my value from the value window, the expression executes correctly (selects the appropriate 129 records).

I'm curious if anyone else has encountered issues similar to this before and if so, how did you handle it?

When I save the feature class as a shapefile, the expression builder works fine and all of the correct available values appear in the window as they are supposed to.  Unfortunatly I'm going to be working with 100+ different datasets, most of which will be in the File Geodatabase format and I really don't want to have to convert all feature classes I need to a shapefile and then after processing, etc have to convert them back to File GeoDatabase Feature classes.